# Reset ViewPager's current item position inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, notifydatasetchanged

I have one parent ViewPager in which I passed FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Now there is another child ViewPager inside Fragment which is in parent ViewPager. So when I try to notifyDataSetChanged of parent ViewPager's adapter, all fragments are recreated but child ViewPager's current item position still remain same as before recreating fragment's child ViewPager's position.

So, how can I reset child ViewPager's current item position?

Answer (score 2):

The current item is tracked by the `ViewPager`, not the adapter.  So wherever you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` you need to add some code such as  `viewPager.setCurrentItem(0)`.